# Angular router not recognizing () in path

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to load an angular component based on same parameters provided in router path. My path looks like such.

```
  {
    path: ':code/:country',
    component: CardViewComponent,
    resolve: {
      configuration: CardViewService
    }
  },
```

First, i am lazy loading my module and in that nodules router i am trying to load the above component. The lazy loading of the module is

```
 {
    path: 'main/chapters',
    loadChildren: () => import('./features/chapter.module').then(m => m.ChapterModule),
  },
```

Every thing works fine but the problem arises when `()` are passed in as the parameter for this route.
For example

```
/main/chapters/Au/Australia
```

results in proper output but when it becomes something like

```
/main/chapters/Au/Australia(Old)
```

The component is not loaded. But again if the brackets are removed then every thing works fine. I have tried `encodeUriComponent` but it did not help. And changing the url is not an option for me.

Can any body guide me with this. I have also searched for github issues
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10280
but could not get much out of it. Really looking forward to some solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround provided in the GitHub link does work.

```
encodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}

const url = `/main/chapters/Au/${this.encodeURIComponent('Australia(Old)')}`;
this.router.navigate(url);
```

[**Github Issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4895#issuecomment-150922834)

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-routing-iwpf1z)